# Designing a correct table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

We are trying to save the **Family History** of a particular foreign job applicant. Below are the details we have to save.

```
Familiy Member: Father|Mother|1st Brother| 2nd Brother| 1st Sister| etc etc

Health Status: Alive|Deceased

Health Condition (Negative/Positive): Arthritis |Asthma |COPD |Diabetes  etc etc

Health Condition (Comment): Arthritis |Asthma |COPD |Diabetes  etc etc

Overall Comment
```

Below is its UI, so you can understand it better.

[image]

Now our problem creating a database table for storing these information. Below are the things to be considered.

1. If the job applicant like, he can provide the data of any number of family members.
2. There are hundreds of items to come under "General Data". So we can't create columns in table for every single items in that.
3. "Overall History Comment" is a comment about the entire family history, not related to a particular member.

The table design we made is below
[image]

Here are some sample input to the table.

**FamilyHistory**

```
a) 1,1,1st Brother,Alive, Asthma, Not serious
b) 2,1,1st Brother,Alive, Cancer, Lung Cancer
c) 3,2,2nd Sister,Alive, Asthma,serious
d) 4,2,2nd Sister,Alive, Diabetes,serious
```

**OverallComment**

```
a) 1,1,1,Overall Condition Normal
b) 2,3,2,NULL
```

However we feel this design is bad due to the below points.

1. Have a look at the a) and b) of **Family History** input. The 1st brother of the job applicant have 2 health conditions. To enter this, 2 rows are inserted and all the details about him are repeated except the different health conditions.

Can you please let me know how to make this design better?

Comment: I think this kind of question is better located at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better fit for this, seeing as it is strictly a database *design* question, rather than a programming one - "Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity" is explicitly included in the "What topics can I ask about here?" section of that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is: Why do you record this data? What is it good for? I cannot imagine its use. However, the answer will help design.

Is it important whether the second sister or the father has arthritis? If not, then why distinguish the two? You could go without Family member types. (If you want so use a text field where you type in '2nd sis', 'mom', 'father', whatever.)

Are you going to have reports on that (e.g. 20% of our applicants told us they have family members with cancer)? Or will you always simply look up one applicant and see their family entries? If the latter, you could make this one text column where you simply type in all members and their health (or have your program write this).

Another point: Why is OverallComment a separate table? Do you need this for internationalization? Or for database-wide text search? If not, make this a column in the related table instead.

```
applicant ( applicant_id , name , comment )
```

If you need the relational model for queries and reports, then have one table for the family member:

```
family_member ( family_member_id , applicant_id , family_member_type, alive, comment )
```

And another table for the several desease entries per member:

```
family_member_desease ( family_member_id , desease_id , comment )
```

Maybe you should add dates. E.g.: When was the father reported to be alive?

Comment: anyway, imagine this.. When the user "tick" on the disease, we add that to the `family_member_desease` table. what happens when user "untick" a already ticked disease ? Basically we have to search and delete that record from `family_member_desease` table?

Comment: So you want to edit this later? I thought you would just enter the data once and be done with it. But yes, if you need this in such structured form, then removing a desease means removing the record, i.e. delete it. `delete from family_member_desease where family_member_id = 1 and desease_id = 2;`. If you even need the comment still, then add a flag instead. Then it is just an update instead of delete. `update family_member_desease set healed = true where family_member_id = 1 and desease_id = 2;`